# How can I use cocoafish/cocoafish-ios-sdk/samples/DemoApp on github.com, facebook check-in sample?

Tags: facebook, checkin

Nowadays, I develop facebook checkin of iPhone app.

So, I searched sample on github.com and found cocoafish/cocoafish-ios-sdk/samples/DemoApp.

I built this and executed this app and I clicked "Login with Facebook" on user tab.
After typing email and password and clicking "Login", this app doesn't login with Facebook.
It prompts "Failed to login with Facebook, Authentication needed".

My email and password are correct.

Also my cocoafishAppKey, oauthConsumerKey, oauthConsumerSecret and facebookAppId are correct.

My cocoafishAppKey, oauthConsumerKey and facebookApp are same and these are the AppId/AppKey that i made when i add app into facebook.

And oauthConsumerSecret is Secret Key.

then, how can i execute this app?
I am going to reference this app.
I will wait answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is Wei from Cocoafish. We provide a server backend so that developers can build checkins and other networked features into their mobile apps. Currently, our Facebook support allows users in your app to also login with their Facebook account.

If you have already signed up for the Cocoafish Private Beta, please refer to http://cocoafish.com/docs/ios#facebook for instructions on how to connect your app to allow Facebook logins. If you don't yet have access to Cocoafish, please sign up at http://cocoafish.com/beta/signup and note that you are coming from StackOverflow so that we can give you a beta access code. If you have any more detailed questions, please email wei@cocoafish.com.

Thanks!

Wei